# Nginx error when serving 2 projects with the same IP and port

Tags: nginx

First of all, I apologize if any words are not understood correctly, since my English is not very good.

I am trying to serve two projects, which I have housed in the same machine, in different locations. I want to call these two projects using a single ip and port, but different directories:

- *Test.example.com/advanceerp*
- *Test.example.com/phpmyadmin*

The setup should be very easy. I get *nginx* show me the *project1* without problems, but when trying to serve the *project2* indicates a 404 error. If I check the log, I see that when it tries to serve this project, it is looking at the root of the project called advance ... I have configured two Virtual host on my *sites-enabled* as follows:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name test.example.com;

    location /advanceerp {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name test.example.com;

    location /phpmyadmin {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I have a short time using *nginx,* so I understand that it must be a beginner error, please do not keep me in mind;) What would be the easiest way to do this? A cordial greeting and thanks in advance.

---

Yes, I just simplified the configuration of sites-enabled. Leaving a single file and inside the configuring several locations that point to different projects ... This also does not work for me, it indicates a 404 error.

```
Server {

    Listen 80;
    Listen [::]: 80 ipv6only = on;

    Index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    Root / var / www / html;
    Server_name test.fasttracknet.es;

    Location / {
        Try_files $ uri = 404;
    }

    Location / advanceerp {
        root /var/www;
        Try_files $ uri $ uri / = 404;
    }

    Location /phpmyadmin {
        root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
        Try_files $ uri $ uri / = 404;
    }

    Location ~ \ .php $ {
        Include snippets / fastcgi-php.conf;
        Fastcgi_pass unix: /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    Location ~ /\.ht {
        Deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second configuration cannot work like you have put into the question. nginx might accept capital letters in directives, but it cannot accept spaces here and there in the configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Your configuration for `test.example.com` works so that `http://test.example.com/phpmyadmin` points to `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin`.

It works this way because you have specified `root` as `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` and `location` as `/phpmyadmin`. nginx appends the value of `location` to value of `root` to determine the location of the file.

In your case, I would use the following configuration for `test.example.com`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /path/to/empty/dir;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name test.example.com;

    location /phpmyadmin {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Here we use the `alias` directive to specify the exact filesystem path for the `location /phpmyadmin`.

The `/path/to/empty/dir` is the directory you want to show when `http://test.example.com` is accessed.

Answer (score -1):

You have the `root` directive in the `server` block for both servers, so the second entry overrides the first.

Move the `root` directive for your apache in to the `location` block:

```
server {
    server_name test.example.com;
    root /var/www/;
}

server {
    server_name test.example.com;
    location /phpmyadmin {
        root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
    }
}
```

Note: You might be tempted to move all `root` directives into their `location` blocks, but [the nginx documentation advises against that](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Maybe I created some confusion in my post. I wanted to say that I have two files with the configuration of each of the virtual host:

project1 and project2


.When I try to make a request to the URL: example.com/phpmyadmin, I check the log that you are trying to go to / var / www instead of going to / usr / share / phpmyadmin. Why does this happen?

A greeting.

Comment: Have you tried moving the `root` directive in the `location` block?

Comment: Yes, I just simplified the configuration of sites-enabled. Leaving a single file and inside the configuring several locations that point to different projects ... This also does not work for me, it indicates a 404 error. My question is, what is the easiest way to serve several projects with nginx (separated in different directories), using a single machine, with the same ip and same port?

A cordial greeting.

Comment: This does not work. `location` is always `root`-relative. You should either have `alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin;` or `root /usr/share;`. Also, you now have to two `server { server_name test.example.com; }` sections instead of just having a modifying `location { }` inside a single  `server { }`.

Comment: Very Thanks! At the moment , my problem is solved.